# Fault tolerant reader writer access to shared resource

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, locking, lock-free

I am currently prototyping an application which maintains a shared resource in shared memory and can be updated by a single writer by read by multiple readers ( typically 4 ). The readers and the writers run as a separate process. The writer updates the shared memory much more frequently than the readers reading from it.

The shared resource is an array of structs with each struct having a lock to protect access to it. The write acquires the lock and writes the latest value for elements[i] and releases the lock.

```
struct Data
{
  int a;
  int b;
  char[10]; c
  Lock l;
};

struct Data elements[ 10000 ];
```

I'm facing with the following challenges

1) The Lock l should have minimum overhead.
2) Since we have many readers, I'm looking for something with reader writer semantics.
3) If one of the process crashes the lock should be gracefully released.

Could someone points to some literature on these please ? Would appreciate if you could share you experience on solving similar challenges.

I will be implementing the solution in C++
Thanks.

Comment: This is going to be slightly painful.  If a process exits while holding a write lock, you can deal with that by using a separate magic value for each process (maybe based on PID).  But if a process exits while it holds one of many read locks?  You have to free the right number.  Probably best to use the kernel-supported locks provided by the OS, instead of rolling your own via interlocked operations in shared memory.

Comment: Did you see that: man pthread_rwlock_rdlock

Comment: And for me there are 2 unclear questions:

1. Do you need to verify read and perform readlock? If you are using shared memory - you can use shmem_ctl for that in Linux (SHM_LOCK/SHM_UNLOCK).
2. Is it platform independend solution? If so - you need wrapper classes to hide implementation details.